# Android (Galaxy S8) not showing Bluetooth "Available Devices" screen

Tags: bluetooth

My Galaxy S8 is no longer showing "Available Devices" screen when I enable Bluetooth. I used to be able to see a list of available devices when I enabled Bluetooth.

Can this be fixed? Thanks in advance.

https://www.techjunkie.com/samsung-galaxy-s8-and-galaxy-s8-bluetooth-pairing-mode/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is still there of not getting the auto-pop up, but I am closing this since you can still work around it by going to Settings > Connections, and clicking on Bluetooth (next to its On/Off toggle) to see the list of available devices.